# Trying to get the date range boundaries of a google daterangefilter

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've hooked up an event listener to notify me when the values on the slider change. However, I'm not able to read them.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(dfHistorical,'statechange',function(e) {

                    alert("Min value: " + dfHistorical.getOption('minValue') + " Max value: " + dfHistorical.getOption('maxValue'));

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `'state'` property of the *DateRangeFilter* has four properties...

> `lowValue` - The lower extent of the selected range, inclusive.
>
> `highValue` - The higher extent of the selected range, inclusive.
>
> `lowThumbAtMinimum` - Whether the lower thumb of the slider is locked at the minimum allowed range. If set, overrides `lowValue`.
>
> `highThumbAtMaximum` - Whether the higher thumb of the slider is locked at the maximum allowed range. If set, overrides `highValue`.

to access the properties, use the `getState()` method

`DateRangeFilter.getState().lowValue`

e.g.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(dfHistorical, 'statechange', function () {
  var valHigh = dfHistorical.getState().highValue;
  var valLow = dfHistorical.getState().lowValue;

  console.log(valLow, valHigh);
});
```

Comment: hope this helps, see [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#daterangefilter) for the rest of the methods...